# I2C gives I/O- Errors and EEPROM only gives 0x00

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock, i2c, eeprom

I got some troubles with my **Pi Zero W (Stretch)** and my **SparkFun AS7265x** Sensor(https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/c/2/9/0 ... asheet.pdf):
I connected them over my GPIOs and created an **I2C Bus**:

- I detected my **sensor at 0x49** via "i2cdetect -y 1"
- I configured my rapsi-config (enable i2c)
- I installed the **drivers i2c-tools**, used the **mods i2c-dev and i2c-bcm2708** and edited to my boot/config.txt additionally "dtoverlay=i2c1-bcm2708" and put pi to group i2c for no carrying any longer a sudo with myself.....

--> Now I want to read out some registers e.g. the temperature (0x06) but **everything I get is a 0x00** ("i2cget -y 1 0x49 0x06 b")
--> The only register I can read is 0x00 and there I get 0x80 (but             default should be 0x40)

so I tried pyserial, but when I want to use: serial.Serial("/dev/i2c-1", 115200) --> I get a **cannot configure port error 25** 
if I write cat /dev/i2c-1 (as explained in some stack overflow topics) I get an **I/O-Error**.....

I am pretty keyless now.... Maybe there is a clock stretching, but none is mentioned in the data sheet ??

Would be likely if anybody could help me :)

Cheers!

```
raise SerialException("Could not configure port: {}".format(msg)) 
 serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Comment: Well, python's Serial.serial is for uart, so that won't work with i2c. Have you got another i2c device you could try?

Comment: on Monday I will receive an UART adapter to connect to my sensor, but this includes some soldering work, which is usually untypical for SparkFun devices...? -- Usually simply plug and play devices ...